# Understanding notation regarding the convolution of Dirac measures.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

As part of my self-study, I am reading a text that uses the following notation to explain the convolution of Dirac measures $\delta_{a}$ and $\delta_{b}$:

$[\delta_{a} * \delta_{b}](B) = \delta_{b}(T_{-a}(B)) = \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } b \in T_{-a}(B) \Longleftrightarrow a + b \in B = \delta_{a+b}(B)\\
        0 & \text{else }
    \end{cases}$

(Note that B is a Borel set).

Would someone be able to quickly explain the notation for me, particularly $T_{-a}(B)$ and why the double implication $b \in T_{-a}(B) \Longleftrightarrow a + b \in B$ holds?

More generally, I am trying to understand why the following formula holds:

$\delta_{x}*\delta_{y} = \delta_{x+y}$

Comment: What exactly is $T$ supposed to be? Some translation operator?

Comment: Okay, it looks like we have $T_x(B) = x+B = \{x+b: b\in B\}$. Hence $b\in T_{-a}(B)$ means that there exists some $c\in B$ such that $b = -a + c$, or $c = b+a$, and hence $b+a\in B$.

Comment: $b \in T_{-a}(B) \iff \exists \beta \in (B) s.t. b = T_{-a}(\beta) \iff b=\beta-a \iff a+b=\beta \iff b = a + b \in B$

Comment: For any complex measures $\nu$, $\mu$ on the real line, $\mu*\nu(A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbb{1}_A(x+y)\,\mu\otimes\nu(dx,dy)$.By Fubini-Toneli's theorem $\mu*\nu(A)=\int_\mathbb{R}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{A-x}(y)\,\nu(dy)\Big)\mu(dx)$. Notice that $\mathbb{1}_{A}(x+y)=\mathbb{1}_{A-x}(y)=\mathbb{1}_{A-y}(x)$ for all $x,y$.